JDK installed, why Jdeps and Jlink not working?
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>java --version
java 22.0.1 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>jdeps
'jdeps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>jlink
'jlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

maybe I'm missing something, but why aren't jdeps and jlink commands working?

You most likely havn't added the full bin folder from your java installation on your system path.
Seems like a good walkthrough How to Set Java Path On Windows?
